# Count the amount of different category id?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have the following array like this :

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [rec_id] => 4
            [mid] => a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"5";}
            [cid] => 5
            [lang] => geo
            [title] => ჯიმი მორისონი გაცოცხლდა
            [intro] =>
            [img] => xhdvlmvogeujm76.jpg
        [text] =>

        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 7
            [rec_id] => 6
            [mid] => a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"5";}
            [cid] => 3
            [lang] => geo
            [title] => 70 people died
            [intro] =>
            [img] => as554ghbvwe5.jpg
        [text] =>

        )




)
```

What I want to do is count how many different Cid (category id) are in my items. Let's say I have 5 items with each a different cid, then counter should return 5, if 3 out of these 5 have the same cid, then it returns 3 and so on. I've been tempering with `foreach()` but no luck . here what i tried

```
foreach ($data as $k=>$v)
{
    if ($v['cid']!=$v['cid']){
        $counter=$counter+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You check if `$v` cid is different from `$v` cid... Uhm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.5+ you can use

```
$uniqueCids = array_unique(
    array_column(
        $myArray,
        'cid'
    )
);
```

For PHP < 5.5, you can use

```
$uniqueCids = array_unique(
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return $value['cid'];
        },
        $myArray
    )
);
```

Then just do

```
$uniqueCidCount = count($uniqueCids);
```

Comment: and use count() to count